# Flask Admin: Add property of related object to column list in model view

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I have the following db model:

```
class Sentence(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sentences'
    sentence_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)                                        
    sentence_text = db.Column(db.String(1024), unique=False, nullable=False)
    records = db.relationship('Record', backref='sentence', lazy='dynamic')
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Sentence id=%r>' % (self.sentence_id)


class Record(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'records'
    record_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)                                                
    sentence_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sentences.sentence_id'), nullable=False)
```

In my flask-admin backend, I would like to display the sentence_text in my record view.

I created a custom model view:

```
class RecordView(sqla.ModelView):
    column_list = ('record_id', 'sentence', 'sentence_text',)
```

However, sentence_text is not shown.

[image]

How would I achieve this?

Comment: I added a property 'sentence_text' to my Record class, like so:
`@property
def sentence_text(self):
        return self.sentence.sentence_text`
But this seems redundant, no?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a suitable string representation to your models. Flask-Admin will use this for output.

For example, [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__):

```
class Sentence(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sentences'
    sentence_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sentence_text = db.Column(db.String(1024), unique=False, nullable=False)
    records = db.relationship('Record', backref='sentence', lazy='dynamic') 

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sentence_text
```

[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

```
class Sentence(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sentences'
    sentence_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sentence_text = db.Column(db.String(1024), unique=False, nullable=False)
    records = db.relationship('Record', backref='sentence', lazy='dynamic') 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sentence_text
```

To reference a property of a related object use the dotted path:

```
class RecordView(sqla.ModelView):
    column_list = ('record_id', 'sentence', 'sentence.sentence_text')
```

Comment: Thanks. I already had a string representation of my sentence objects. The second column of my screenshot show what it looks like, but I still would like to have the sentence text apart. I added it in the code above to make things clearer.

Comment: @Zuabi - Updated. `__repr__` and `__str__` are not the same. `__repr__` is typically used for debugging whilst `__str__` is the informal or 'nice' output.